# Is there any application/software/web tool that creates customized search engine

Tags: search, customization, search-engine, classification, google-custom-search

I wonder if there is any application/software or tool that creates a customized search engine and then the results will be classified according to the websites I've defined before.

What I want is combining the World Wide News websites lets say they are 4 sites and then when I search for Global Warming the results are classified according to the sites I specified earlier.

CNN.COM retrieves 509655 global warming

BBC.CO.UK  retrieves 303255 global warming

ABC.COM retrieves 4588 global warming

ALJAZEERA.COM retrieves 2699 global warming

Is it possible? is there anything can do like this

Answer (score 0):

Give Apache Solr a try.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

From the website:

> Solr is the popular, blazing-fast, open source enterprise search platform built on Apache Lucene™